# Not get result while calling balance summary API(Node JS) of Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I want to get a balance summary of my stripe transaction. So I used the balance summary API.

Result getting null here

```
{
  id: 'akdgfajhdja',
  object: 'reporting.report_run',
  created: 1683696387,
  error: null,
  livemode: true,
  parameters: {
    columns: [ 'category', 'description', 'net_amount', 'currency' ],
    interval_end: 1682879399,
    interval_start: 1680287401,
    timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  report_type: 'balance.summary.1',
  result: null,
  status: 'pending',
  succeeded_at: null
}
```

This is the code for creating report

```
let reportRun = await stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create({
      report_type: "balance.summary.1",
      parameters: {
        interval_start: data.startDate,
        interval_end: data.endDate,
        timezone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        columns: ["category", "description", "net_amount", "currency"],
      },
    });
console.log(reportRun);
```

Comment: `result` field will only be populated when the status is `succeeded` (reference from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/reporting/report_run/object#reporting_report_run_object-result)). Since the report run status is in `pending`, `result` won't be populated.

Comment: You should listen to `reporting.report_type.updated` event for the report status update with `status='succeeded'` as the integration steps suggested here: https://stripe.com/docs/reports/api#integration-pattern